# php code syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, gd

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this php snippet? I'm trying to integrate GD Star Rating into my wordpress comments and got this code from http://www.placementedge.com/blog/gd-star-rating-comment-integration-with-wordpress-3-0/#comment-2952 - thanks!

```
<?php
$form_args = array(
    'title_reply_to' => __('Reply to %s'), // SHOWS SYNTAX ERROR
    'title_reply' => __('Post a Review'),   // SHOWS SYNTAX ERROR
    'comment_field' => wp_gdsr_comment_integrate_multi_rating($multi_set_id = 1,     
$template_id = 0, $value = 0, $stars_set = "oxygen", $stars_size = 24, 
$stars_set_ie6 = "oxygen", $echo = false).'<p class="comment-  
form-comment"><label for="comment">My 
Review</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
'comment_notes_after' => __(''));
comment_form( $form_args );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `=&gt;` to `=>` in your code.

```
<?php
$form_args = array(
    'title_reply_to' => __('Reply to %s'), // SHOWS SYNTAX ERROR
    'title_reply' => __('Post a Review'),   // SHOWS SYNTAX ERROR
    'comment_field' => wp_gdsr_comment_integrate_multi_rating($multi_set_id = 1,     
$template_id = 0, $value = 0, $stars_set = &quot;oxygen&quot;, $stars_size = 24, 
$stars_set_ie6 = &quot;oxygen&quot;, $echo = false).'&lt;p class=&quot;comment-  
form-comment&quot;&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;comment&quot;&gt;My 
Review&lt;/label&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;textarea id=&quot;comment&quot; name=&
quot;comment&quot; aria-required=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;/p&gt;',
'comment_notes_after' => __(''));
comment_form( $form_args );
```

Comment: Thanks everyone and I copied this over (and first reply) which works so thanks I'm a bit stupid never mind.

Answer (score 1):

replace `&gt;` with > where it is not in the  quotes ''

```
'title_reply_to' => __('Reply to %s'),
'title_reply' => __('Post a Review'),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$form_args = array(
    'title_reply_to' => __('Reply to %s'), // SHOWS SYNTAX ERROR
    'title_reply' => __('Post a Review'),   // SHOWS SYNTAX ERROR
    'comment_field' => wp_gdsr_comment_integrate_multi_rating($multi_set_id = 1,     
$template_id = 0, $value = 0, $stars_set = "oxygen", $stars_size = 24, 
$stars_set_ie6 = "oxygen", $echo = false).'&lt;p class="comment-  
form-comment">&lt;label for="comment">My 
Review&lt;/label>&lt;br />&lt;textarea id="comment" name=&
quot;comment" aria-required="true">&lt;/textarea>&lt;/p>',
'comment_notes_after' => __(''));
comment_form( $form_args );
```

Comment: i have changed the quotes tooo

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `&gt;` by `>`

It's PHP, not HTML.